# How do I put my StackOverflow User Flair on my blogger blog?

Tags: discussion, flair

I have a blog hosted by blogger, and I'd like to add StackOverflow's "user flair" to the sidebar or something. How do I do that?

Comment: go to your flair page: "/users/USER-ID/flair" and read the instructions.

Comment: I did that, and it would be fine if I was editting the full HTML of my blog, instead of using blogger and needing to place something there.

Comment: @Mehrdad:this would be the best answer if it were not be comment

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a third party service not related to Stack Exchange. 

Comment: @AsheeshR it's about the user flair which is totally on topic.

Comment: Since flair is a plain image nowadays, the answers to this question are pretty much obsolete now.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In Blogger, go to `Layout -> Add Gadget`

Select `HTML/JavaScript` gadget from the list.

[image]

Now go to flair tab in your SO profile page. Copy paste that code in this gadget content part(You can leave title part empty if you wish).

To change the theme add `?theme=clean or ?theme=dark` to the end of the image URL and you are done!

You can view my Flair : [blog](http://opensourceforgeeks.blogspot.in/)

Comment: The one caveat is that the flair does not work (or at least I was not able to make it work), if you set you blog theme to Dynamic Views.

Answer (score 29):

**EDIT: This is a deprecated method and eventually it won't work.**

First you need to go to the settings menu, and then click on the Layout tab.

What I did was that I added a "Gadget" to the right column, of type Text.

Then, once the Text editing dialog was shown, click on the HTML view, and then paste in the code necessary.

What I have on my blog is this:

```
<iframe scrolling="no" frameborder="0" width="210px"
    src="http://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/267.html?theme=clean" marginheight="0"
    height="60px" marginwidth="0"></iframe>
<iframe scrolling="no" frameborder="0" width="210px"
    src="http://serverfault.com/users/flair/345.html?theme=clean" marginheight="0"
    height="60px" marginwidth="0"></iframe>
```

I found that using the javascript version didn't fit well, so you might want to experiment, but the above [works for me](http://presentationmode.blogspot.com). Note that I didn't bother with the CSS changes, so my flair is shown with a white background even though my blog uses a green background.

Comment: +1 - Not sure why this was voted down - you answered the question really well...

Comment: Made it CW since this is basically off-topic.

Comment: I didn't answer it to begin with, I just posted "I'll dig up the details", so I understand the downvote, but people should perhaps *read* the answers and *understand* them before they downvote. My original 1-liner answer just said "Hang on, let me find the details and edit my answer".

Comment: and why on earth did you think it was necessary?

Comment: +1 for the nice answer. (Although I *do* believe the downvote for a non-answer was well-deserved (it wasn't from me))

Comment: I've found that some off-topic questions are best served by a "Hang on, let me work out the real answer for you", both to give the person asking a hope of getting an answer (because you can't add an answer once the question is closed), and perhaps let the people closing it a sense of "ok, let's wait until this person has answered it".

Comment: Actually, Lasse, your "hang on" answer is just insurance that your answer is posted first.

Comment: "posted first" doesn't count. Voted up the most counts more. I use these "hang on" type of answers sparingly, and only when I assume the question will be closed pretty quick and I actually have an answer that I'd like to post. So if by "first", you mean "only answer before it was closed", then yes, I'd like to ensure that if I can. Are you saying that's wrong?

Comment: And just to make the point: I'm not going to change my behavior due to these comments. If I see a similar situation in the future, being a question which is probably going to be closed soon and I actually have an answer that would help, then I will do the same again. Downvote me if you disagree. Rep doesn't matter the slightest at this point anyway.

Comment: Nope, it's not wrong. See the "fastest gun in the west" post that was made back around August or September. 'Posted first' does count. It gives you the spot to fill in later. It's even suggested as a technique to get more rep in the 'how do I get 200 rep a day' question.

Comment: Well, Lasse, your answer sure did help me, and there was no where else I could have made it at the time. Nowadays we have the meta stack overflow, which would do fine for this.

Comment: This is not working anymore or it's just me?

Answer (score 5):

Maybe Blogger has evolved since this was originally answered, but I just started my blog on blogger.com and wanted to add my flair. Following the answer from @Lasse, I did add a Gadget. However, now, it seems that there is a HTML/Javascript gadget.

Once the gadget is added, simply past your flair *code* inside the text box and *voila!*. You can check out the result on my [blog](http://bits-soft.blogspot.com/)

Comment: This one works. Just tried it :-)

Answer (score 3):

If your using the Dynamic Views, you can add the text gadget as the HTML/Javascript gadget doesn't seem to work. This also applies if you're using classic themes. I made a blog post of how to do it [here](http://www.justanothercarl.com/2012/12/adding-stackoverflow-flair-in-blogger.html).

Comment: its working man

Comment: Its work. Thankyou for your post & simply way to add the flair through pictures.

Answer (score 2):

You maybe find solution for you at this SO question - [What Third Party Tools Exist To Use With Stackoverflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/248296/what-third-party-tools-exist-to-use-with-stackoverflow)

---

[StackOverflow.com Badge to display in your Blog](http://pietschsoft.com/post.aspx?id=36e89f5e-4e11-4a73-81c6-3dde5c757fba)

> This is a user control written in
>   ASP.NET, but could be easily converted
>   for other server-side platforms, or
>   even converted to JavaScript with the
>   help of a JSON service.