# How do I embed StackOverflow flair in my Windows Live Blog?

Tags: discussion, flair

I see a similar question [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10497/how-do-i-put-my-stackoverflow-user-flair-on-my-blogger-blog). But I am unable to figure out how to add custom HTML to the Windows Live blog. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a comment on this to http://x-evolutionist.spaces.live.com/Blog/cns!25A0033DD834DD1D!12748.entry. I attempted to add the flair both through iframe and script, and neither worked - they were both stripped from the HTML. I then tried pasting in the result of https://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/76337.html, and left the result on my [Spaces](http://johnwsaundersiii.spaces.live.com/) page so you can see what does not get stripped.

Comment: John, thank you. That would be static data, right?

Comment: Looks like it's not possible. :(

Comment: :-( what a let down by Windows Live.

Comment: I will mark this as an answer. I will probably update the markup returned by my SO flair page. My reputation on SO does not increase by much everyday anyway. :-) Thank you John and Jon.